# How to attach a debugger to Azure App Service with path mapping in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, asp.net-core

I have an Azure App Service called xxx, and I deployed a asp.net core project to path: xxx/api, I want to attach a remote debugger to xxx/api other than xxx to help me test a remote workflow. How can I achieve this in visual studio?

If I just click the app service in cloud explorer and click "Attach debugger", The debug did start but my breakpoints can't be fired. It says there is no symbol to attach to.

I've checked with my app service and the "Remote Debugging" is on.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here, but make sure you've deployed a debug build and not a release build. You won't be able to attach to a release build.

Comment: Thank you, I do have a debug build when deploy, but the remote debugger still can't fire breakpoints.